# Base64 decode not giving value in php

Tags: php

I have a post value from a form, which contains an array. This value is first serialized and then base64 encoded before it is put in a session.

Now on the page where the data is needed, when i print_r to screen, i can see the value stored in the session as

```
YToxOntpOjA7czo1OiIzNTAwMCI7fQ==
```

Which is actually `35000`.

But on this page where i am supposed to retrieve the data from the session, i am able to get the value from the session and store in a variable

```
$screeningamountt = $_SESSION['SCREENINGAMOUNT'];
```

But when i try to first unserialize and base64 decode the varaible to get the data which is supposed to be 35000, I get an empty variable. Noting prints to screen.

```
$screeningamount = base64_decode(unserialize($screeningamountt));
```

I can't figure out whats happening. Any help to figuring whats going on is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to treat your session data special at all. You don't have to serialize _or_ encode it at all.

Comment: ^^^That, why not just `35000`?

Comment: @Sammitch I serialized it because the post could be an array of multiple values and serializing it reduces it to a string of characters. Encoding it just adds some little security to the data.

Comment: Ok, but you still don't have to do that. The session handler will give back exactly what you put in. Also base64 encoding adds exactly 0% security. Anyone who has ever seen base64 before will look at it and go "that's base64-encoded". _and yet further still_ if you're in a position that causes you to be concerned about the security of your session data you've already lost.

Comment: @Sammitch So if i get you right, you are you saying i don't need to base64 encode that data. But i can still serializing it? Or is storing arrays as arrays in sessions a good practice?

Comment: Correct. Serializing the data is unnecessary and only adds overhead.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks for the lessons. Much appreciated. Will modify code now without serializing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you serialize it first then base64 encode it you need to unencode it then unserialize.

Last in, first out.

`$screeningamount = unserialize(base64_decode($screeningamountt));`

Comment: Thanks @justrusty. It did not occur to me that i had to reverse the order. It works as i need it to now.